# Value resets in textfield when dropdown value is changed

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

The values of textfield resets whenever there is a change in dropdown field or even when you click drop down field.
Here is the code..

```
list.forEach((i) {
  var textEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  textEditingControllers.add(textEditingController);
  textFields.add(
    new Column(
      children:[
      new DropdownButton<String>(
        value: _selection[i],
        items: _items.map((String item){
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value:item,
            child: new Text(item), 
            );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (s){
          setState(() { 
           _selection[i]=s;  
          });
        },
      ),
      new TextField(
          autocorrect: false,
          controller: textEditingController,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,  
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,                 
         decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "credit $i",hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[100])),
      )
      ]
    )
  );

 return textFields;
});
```

[full code](https://gist.github.com/spdhiraj99/b618cf56ea76baae0912ba3b51dbffe1)

Is there something that i'm doing wrong?

Crosslink https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18592

Comment: i think it's better if you post all the code

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: I think you need to keep the `TextEditingController` instances instead of recreating them in every `build()` call

Comment: Tried that too, doesn't work

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You were right, i had to keep the TextEditingController instances. i kept the List but didn't keep all the instances. Thanks bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have missed what @Gunter meant by keeping TextEditingController instances. They should be saved into your `State` subclass.

Here's an example (I cleaned up your code a bit too as it was difficult to figure out what was going on).

```
class GPAcalc extends StatefulWidget {
  final int n;

  GPAcalc(this.n);

  @override
  GPAcalcstate createState() => new GPAcalcstate();
}

class GPAcalcstate extends State<GPAcalc> {
  List<String> _items = ['O', 'A+', 'A', 'B+', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'AB', 'I'].toList();
  var _selection = new List<String>();

  var _controllers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllers = new List.generate(widget.n, (i) => new TextEditingController());
    _selection.addAll(_items);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int sogxc = 0, soc = 0;

    var textFields = new List.generate(widget.n, (i) => i)
        .map(
          (i) => new Column(
                children: [
                  new DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: _selection[i],
                    items: _items.map((String item) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: item,
                        child: new Text(item),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (s) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selection[i] = s;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  new TextField(
                    autocorrect: false,
                    controller: _controllers[i],
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "credit ${i + 1}", hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[100])),
                  )
                ],
              ),
        )
        .toList(growable: false);
    double res = 0.0;

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
      ),
      body: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 5.0)),
        child: new ListView(
          children: textFields,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: 'Calculate',
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
        child: new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
        onPressed: () {
          for (int i = 0; i < widget.n; i++) {
            String r = (_controllers[i].text);
            int gp = calculate(_selection[i]);
            int cp = int.parse(r);
            int gxc = gp * cp;
            sogxc += gxc;
            soc += cp;
          }
          res = sogxc / soc;
          Navigator.of(context).push(
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => new ScorePage(res),
                ),
              );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  int calculate(var a) {
    if (a == "O" || a == "o") return 10;
    if (a == "A+" || a == "a+") return 9;
    if (a == "A" || a == "a") return 8;
    if (a == "B+" || a == "b+") return 7;
    if (a == "B" || a == "b") return 6;
    if (a == "C" || a == "c") return 5;
    if (a == "P" || a == "p") return 4;
    if (a == "F" || a == "f") return 0;
    if (a == "AB" || a == "ab") return 0;
    if (a == "I" || a == "i") return 0;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

You want to keep instances of the TextEditingController around for the lifetime of the widget - that way they can manage the value of the text. Also, when you change the value of a dropdown, you have to do it in a `setState(() {})`.

And you can access the variables in your `StatefulWidget` subclass from your `State` subclass at widget.*. That's preferable to passing the parameters through.

Comment: oh ok , i understand what i was doing wrong, i was keeping the array that holds the TextEditingControllers, but since i was creating new Textfields inside loops under build() , the contents of array got replaced with every build.  silly mistakes..duh.. Thanks a lot bro.

Comment: Your code throws this error if the value is above 9 for n, **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..8, inclusive: 9**

Comment: I assume that would be because only 9 default values are created- `['O', 'A+', 'A', 'B+', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'AB', 'I'].toList();` which is left over from your code. I don't know exactly what you mean to do with that so I left it.

Comment: Ya taken care of